# Spark SQL function any type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-sql

I can not design a function to do any numeric type:

```
def array_add_Int(x: WrappedArray[Int], y: WrappedArray[Int]): WrappedArray[Int] = {
    require(x.length == y.length, "ERROR:  cannot operate on arrays of different ranges of dimensions.")    
    x.zipAll(y,0,0).map(pair=>pair._1+pair._2)
}

def array_add_Long(x: WrappedArray[Long], y: WrappedArray[Long]): WrappedArray[Long] = {
    require(x.length == y.length, "ERROR:  cannot operate on arrays of different ranges of dimensions.")    
    x.zipAll(y,0,0).map(pair => pair._1.asInstanceOf[Number].longValue() + pair._2.asInstanceOf[Number].longValue())
}
```

I try to attach the return of the two functions as follows:

```
 def array_add[T](itemX:Traversable[T], itemY:Traversable[T])(implicit n:Numeric[T]) = {
    require(itemX.size == itemY.size, "ERROR:  cannot operate on arrays of different ranges of dimensions.")
    itemX.toSeq.zipAll(itemY.toSeq, 0, 0).map(pair => pair._1 + pair._2)
 }
```

It only work with Int type. Any ideas?

Comment: As a side note, this really doesn't have anything to do with spark or udfs. It's just a plain old Scala question.

Comment: @AngeloGenovese I think it does after all. It is just a part of a long series of questions which started [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35911328/1560062).

Comment: It may be, I am not very familiar with this world.

I want to create this feature to register in SQL Spark , but it does not work.

Comment: @zero323 It may be that he intends to use this function in Spark to define a UDF, but the direct problem he seemed to be having when he asked the question is with base Scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of the Numeric typeclass you're asking for as an implicit argument:

```
def array_add[T](itemX:Traversable[T], itemY:Traversable[T])(implicit n:Numeric[T]) = {
  require(itemX.size == itemY.size, "ERROR:  cannot operate on arrays of different ranges of dimensions.")
  itemX.toSeq.zipAll(itemY.toSeq, n.zero, n.zero).map(pair => n.plus(pair._1, pair._2) )
}
```

note, you can use `n.fromInt()` instead of `n.zero` to handle values other than 0

Comment: com.migracionmadlib.UDFSparkSQL.MADlib$$anonfun$2 cannot be cast to scala.Function1

Comment: By using this function and register in SparkSQL , I get the following exception

Comment: com.migracionmadlib is your own packages? 
What is the line of code associated with this error in the stack trace?

Comment: Looking at the Scala Doc for UDFRegistration, I don't see any way to register a UDF that works across multiple types. You haven't provided the code for the registration you're doing, but you may have to register the UDF for each type you want to support. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/UDFRegistration.html

Comment: @AngeloGenovese You're right, it is not possible. It requires implementing SQL expression not an UDF.